# The number of functions f : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} → {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} such that f (f(n)) = n for all n ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, is :

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I know the functions should be Bijections, the number of bijections are m!= 120, (m = nuber of elements in domain ),But how to proceed for finding the number of functions such that f(f(n))=n ?

Comment: writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Each element $(a)$ that is not mapped to itself, must be paired with an element $(b)$ such that $f(a) = b$ and $f(b) = a.$  Any satisfying function will either have $(0), (1),$ or $(2)$ such pairs.  Enumerate by cases.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590402/number-of-involution-in-symmetric-group) may be related to your question. See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_number_%28mathematics%29) as well.

Comment: Quite a few methods are covered by the answers to the question [Number of functions $f : A \to A$ with $f(f(x)) = x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384714/number-of-functions-f-a-to-a-with-ffx-x). If you have questions regarding any of their approaches, please edit your question to reflect the same.